# Set Table View Controller for section in another table view

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, sections

I have `FirstViewController` (inherits from `UITableViewController`), and I want to show the `SecondViewController` (also inherits from `UITableViewController`) in the first section of `FirstViewController`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: you want a table view inside a table view?

Comment: I want cells from another table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to put the *SecondViewController.view* inside the `UITableViewCell` of the first section/row of your *FirstViewController*.

But maybe the best solution is to create a subclass of `UITableView` (more than `UITableViewController`) and do the same, or add it to the headerView of your *FirstViewController*.

For the code part, try something and come back if you have a problem or more precise question :-)

Anyway, it should works ^^